# xbap custom loader in internet explorer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, clickonce, xbap

I have a xbap application, which works fine. But the problem is that I've nested the xbap app within an iframe. The site`s background color containing the iframe is black. I want to change the xbap application loader (downloader) background color to fit the site appearance.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look into this:

http://scorbs.com/2006/06/28/xbaps-ondemand-clickonce/